# How to fix overlap of functions when importing python packages from the same folder?

Tags: python, import, libraries, python-packaging

I have a folder called `Libs` that has two files (`database.py` and `keyManagementService.py`) I'd like to import as libraries to another file outside of the Libs folder. To do that, I made an `__init__.py` in the Libs folder which looks like this:

```
from Libs.database import *
from Libs.keyManagmentService import *
```

The way I imported the libraries to a file outside of Libs was like this:

```
import Libs as db 
import Libs as kms
```

However, the issue is the functions from the database file overlaps with the functions from the KeyManagementService file, so if I try using `db` for example, the functions from `kms` would also show up. How can I make these libraries standalone for a lack of better wording? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clear the content from `__init__.py` (but leave the empty file), you should be able to

```
from Libs.database import the_exact_names_you_need
from Libs.keyManagementService import the_names_you_need_from_this_file
```